# Why Memoization in Es6 classes with getters/setters is not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a weird problem with getters and setter in Es6 classes. I want to apply the concept of memoization on a getter property, everything seems to work perfectly but not in the strict mode.

```
'use strict';

class obj {
    get name(){
        //memozation
        delete this.name;
        return this.name = "Ahmad";
    }
}
const o1 = new obj();
console.log(o1.name);
```

> #output: **Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "name"**

I've tried to implement the same code using normal javascript object literals and it worked perfectly:

```
'use strict';
    const x1 = {
        get name(){
            //memozation
            delete this.name;
            return this.name = "Ahmad";
        }
    }
    
console.log(x1.name); //#output: Ahmad
```

but before I post this question you may be wondering if I've tried to use a setter, in fact, Yes I did, and this is actually what's mentioned on MDN [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion#Examples),

but the problem is even after using a setter I can see another weird problem: this is the code with a setter:

```
'use strict';

class obj {
    get name(){
        //memozation
        delete this.name;
        return this.name = "Ahmad";
    }
    set name(value){
        this.name = value;
    }
}
const o1 = new obj();
console.log(o1.name);
```

> **#output: Uncaught Error: undefined**

Please note before everything:
I'm using the strict mode, and I'm debugging my code on Mozilla firefox.

How can I fix this problem? and what's the reason for it?

Comment: The property "name" has a getter function. You cannot also use "name" as a simple property.

Comment: before you can call `delete this.name` or `this.name = ...`, you have to create a field `name`. A getter doesn't automatically create a field for you, a getter is just a function. You'll have to define a field at the top of the class `private _name: string` (you don't want to name of the field to conflict with the name of the getter), and then inside the getter you'll do `delete this._name`, `return this._name = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `delete obj[prop]` will *only* "delete" the property `prop` if it's *directly on `obj`*. It will not delete the property if the property is on the *internal prototype*. For another example:

```js
const obj = Object.create({ prop: 'val' });
delete obj.prop;
console.log(obj);
```

In your case, `name` is a property on the protoype:

```
class obj {
    get name(){
```

results in `name` existing only on `obj.prototype`, but not directly on an `o1` instance.

One way to fix it would be to use `Object.defineProperty` inside the getter, to put the property directly onto the instance, so that further references to `this.name` on that instance reference the property directly on the instance, while leaving the getter alone:

```js
'use strict';

class obj {
    get name(){
        console.log('getter invoked');
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', { value: "Ahmad" });
        return this.name;
    }
}
const o1 = new obj();
console.log(o1.name);
console.log(o1.name);
```

Or, with a setter as well:

```js
'use strict';

class obj {
    defineName(value) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', { value, writable: true });
        return this.name;
    }
    get name(){
        console.log('getter invoked');
        return this.defineName("Ahmad");
    }
    set name(value) {
        console.log('setter invoked');
        return this.defineName(value);
    }
}
const o1 = new obj();
o1.name = 'foo';
console.log(o1.name);
console.log(o1.name);
```

Comment: or you can fix it by deleting the property from the prototype directly: delete Object.getPrototypeOf(this).name;  [inside the getter]

Comment: You can do that, but then the lazy initialization won't work anymore for further instances, like for an `o2`

Comment: Yes, that's true, thanks for your second answer, it was a bug that will occur soon in my app. But could you please if you don't mind explain the reason why?

Comment: The prototype object is shared among all instances. `o1 <--- obj.prototype` and `o2 <--- obj.prototype` Doing `delete Object.getPrototypeOf(this).name` deletes the property on the shared prototype, potentially affecting all instances.